# Illegal character in query to maps.googleapis

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I'm developing an Android application that use Google Maps. 
I locate the user and I want to show POIs in the vicinity through a query to maps.googleapis.
In my java code I have a String that I use with HttpRequest to obtain all information. The String is:

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
                "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
                "&radius=1000&sensor=true" +
                "&types=food|bar|store|museum|art_gallery"+
                "&key=myKey";
```

where lat and lng are two variables that contains the coordinates of the position of the user and myKey is my API key. 
When I launch my application in Log section I obtain "Illegal character in query at index 125" and conseguently in the maps I obtain no POIs.
But if I delete all " and + characters in the string and I use the link in browser I obtain a list of POIs.
How can I obtain this list also in my application?? I don't understand where is the error in my String..
thx all

Comment: I'd recommend putting in some print statements to make debugging easier on yourself.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) '|' character should be replace with '%7C'

you can use like this

```
String url=""https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
                "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
                "&radius=1000&sensor=true" +
                "&types=food|bar|store|museum|art_gallery"+
                "&key=myKey";";
url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
```